# How to set an item property of one qml from main.qml

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I waste my time to find how set the visible property to false, the delegate being in an another qml file.

For instance here is a simple example based on Places Map.

Marker.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6

MapQuickItem {
    id: idPointsMarker

    sourceItem: Loader{sourceComponent: idRect}

    visible: true //if set manually to false, everything works correctly

    Component{
        id: idRect
        Rectangle{
            width: 20
            height: 20
            color: "blue"
        }
    }
}
```

and the main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Window {
    width: 512
    height: 512
    visible: true

    PositionSource {
        ...
    }

    property variant locationOslo: QtPositioning.coordinate( 59.93, 10.76)


    PlaceSearchModel {
        ...
    }

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: Plugin {name: "osm"}
        center: locationOslo
        zoomLevel: 13

        MouseArea {
            id : mouseMap
            anchors.fill: parent
            onDoubleClicked: {
                console.log("DoubleClicked")
                Marker.idPointsMarker.visible = false // pb is here

            }
        }

        MapItemView {
            model: searchModel
            delegate: Marker{
                coordinate: place.location.coordinate
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wish to toggle the visibility to false on doubleclick. I am not able to access the property anyhow the way i write it. What is the correct syntax?

Sorry for a so simple question. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to set the property in main.qml, you must do it in Marker.qml, since the elements of Marker.qml can access all the elements of main.qml. One solution is to establish a property of type bool that manages the visibility and that changes in the double click:

**main.qml**

```
Map {
    [...]
    property bool isVisibleItems: true

    MouseArea {
        id : mouseMap
        anchors.fill: parent
        onDoubleClicked: map.isVisibleItems = !map.isVisibleItems
    }
    [...]
```

**Marker.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6

MapQuickItem {
    id: idPointsMarker
    sourceItem: Loader{sourceComponent: idRect}
    visible: map.isVisibleItems

    Component{
        id: idRect
        Rectangle{
            width: 20
            height: 20
            color: "blue"
        }
    }
}
```

In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/48126896) there is an example

Comment: Once again, thank you eyllanesc. I would never have found this solution. So I must totally reverse my mind : main.qml has no visibility on the parameters of other qml, however any other qml has visibility on the main.qml settings ... it's devilishly devious.

Comment: @kontiki read this: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qml-qtquick-loader.html#using-a-loader-within-a-view-delegate

Comment: Done, thanks. I didn't notice a connection between my difficulty to acquire a property value by a call in main and creation of an explicit property in a loader, even if the mind is the same. In my example, loader is only for memory, but if it had been a simple rectangle, my syntax problem and wrong analysis would have been the same, with, I suppose the same solution. To modify any property in a qml other than main we have to modify it from its origin, not in main. A property must be created, in main, for that. What if change a color from a button in menu.qml for action in marquer.qml ?

Comment: Please do not use this as a "solution"! Referencing to an id which is _NOT_ located in same QML file should be avoided at all costs! You have to use so called `dependency injection` pattern and pass all needed properties to the component (`Marker.qml`)